# Acces Google Pub/Sub from outside of GCP

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-pubsub

Is it possible to directly send data to Cloud Pub/Sub from the internet? As far as i understand, this would be only possible using a service account. Is that right?

Answer (score 5):

You can access Cloud Pub/Sub (and other Google Cloud Platform services) from outside the Google Cloud, yes. You need to be authenticated, which means either using a service account or authenticating as an end user who has access to the project. You can read more details in the [Authentication Overview](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/) for Google Cloud Platform. The information is not specific th Cloud Pub/Sub.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. The schema here looks like that:

1. Create a new service account, that will be used for further authentication.
2. Attach "Pub/Sub Editor" role to it (or set more granular permissions
   through IAM) - for authorization.
3. Create an export JSON-key of the newly created service account.
4. In your app outside GCP use the key to be authenticated with enough permissions. For example, in Go applications we could use it with ClientOption of Google API client: `option.WithCredentialsJSON([]byte(JSON_KEY_CONTENT))`

No matter what language/library you use, the main idea is to sign every your request to GCP, using the created service account.

Comment: To send PubSub messages only the role pubsub.publisher on the topic level would be sufficient and more granular.

Comment: @TomaszKubat Yes, definitely. `Editor` role could be used as a basic solution, but for publishing purposes to particular topic only - granular permissions should be used for sure.