# Can I publish an event into Cloud Pub/Sub outside from GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

Can I publish an event into Cloud Pub/Sub outside from GCP?

Let me clarify my query a bit. In AWS as we are able to publish events into SNS topics directly by invoking REST API via API Gateway from the non-cloud client (https://github.com/cdk-patterns/serverless/blob/master/the-big-fan/README.md), is there any such method in GCP to publish an event into Pub/Sub?

I can see there is a similar question in SO ([Acces Google Pub/Sub from outside of GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503084/acces-google-pub-sub-from-outside-of-gcp)), but it is not fully answered my question I believe. Yes authentication is required and it is a cross-cutting functionality, but what is the basic technic to publish an event in Pub/Sub outside from GCP

Comment: i think the post you shared has a pretty simple answer. why it has not fully answered your question? you need to somehow authenticated either service account or PKI from e.g. google iot core. In case you have a device registered with pki in google iot core then you can use event topics to publish to it.

Comment: Do you want an unauthenticated access to your topic?

Comment: No I don't want unauthenticated access to the topic, rather I want to integrate topic with some API Gateway kind of component and expose some REST API by my own via API Gateway. API Gateway will responsible for the user authentication either using API Key or using some identity provider/broker. The communication between API Gateway and topic will be authenticated by service account. Can I implement this design in GCP?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can [publish](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#top_of_page) a message into a topic, and then [pull it](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#top_of_page), or even have PubSub deliver it to you through a [Push subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#top_of_page).

When publishing a message, or pulling it from a subscriber, you can access PubSub through the [REST](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest#top_of_page) or [RPC API](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc#top_of_page). In addition, you can use one of the [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries#top_of_page).

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#publishing_messages) you can find an example of how to publish a message using the `gcloud` CLI tool, an example with the `REST API`, `python` and `java` among other programming languages.

As mentioned in the question referenced, you will need to authenticate in order to either publish a message, or pull it. You can use the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#top_of_page) as a reference on how to do so. Notice that you can follow the quickstart from any computer or VM outside GCP.

Finally, if you're using Push subscriptions to receive your messages, your endpoint will need to be a publicly accessible HTTPS address and have a valid SSL certificate signed by a certificate authority. Again, this endpoint can live outside GCP.

Answer (score 0):

Code connects to PubSub with a Google provided [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries)

In dev, you run these two commands, the auth lasts for a few hours.

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud auth application-default login
```

In Production, copy a JSON file here `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`

e.g.

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "PROJECT_ID",
  "private_key_id": "KEY_ID",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nPRIVATE_KEY\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL",
  "client_id": "CLIENT_ID",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL"
}
```

File is created in the GCloud Web Console: its called a "Service account key".

As you can see, it contains a private key so should be treated as a secret.

There are options for key expiry if you need that, or not if you don't.